# Trying to refactor networking method using Singleton pattern in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, objective-c-blocks

I have the following method in my app which uses `NSURLSession` to pull movie data from a web service in JSON format:

```
- (void) downloadMovieData {

    //this is just a visual cue to show that processing is being done
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    //creating the request
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kMovieURL];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    //creating the session
    self.config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.config];

    //the object that makes the call to the web service using the request and the session, and returns a response or an error
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        //At this point a response has been received, so we can turn the indicator off
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

        //I am casting the response to an NSHTTPURLResponse so I can check the status code of the response
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

        //a status code of 200 means a successful connection with the web service
        if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSLog(@"Success!");
                //I send the data that was received from the response to the method so that the JSON data is extracted
                [self populateArray:data];
            });

        } else {
            NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Received HTTP %ld: %@", (long)httpResponse.statusCode, result);
        }
    }];

    [task resume];

}

- (void) populateArray: (NSData *)data {

    NSError *jsonError;
    NSDictionary *response =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];

    if (response) {
        self.movieObjects = response[@"movies"];
        NSLog(@"The movie objects are: %@", self.movieObjects);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", jsonError);
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine.  No issues.  However, what I would like to do now, is refactor my code so that rather having all my networking code in the class that contains my `UITableView` delegate methods, I want to move the code in a separate class which uses a Singleton method for better separation of code.  I have the following skeleton code for this which looks like the following:

```
#import "Networker.h"

@implementation Networker

+ (NSURLSession *)dataSession {
    static NSURLSession *session = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    });
    return session;
}

+ (void)fetchContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url completion:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSError *error)) completionHandler {

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [[self dataSession] dataTaskWithURL:url
                      completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

         if (completionHandler == nil) return;

         if (error) {
             completionHandler(nil, error);
             return;
         }
         completionHandler(data, nil);
     }];

    [dataTask resume];
}
```

I have no problems understanding the Singleton class at all.  This is not the issue.  My issue is understanding how to understand the "completion handler" portion of this method:

```
+ (void)fetchContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url completion:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSError *error)) completionHandler {}
```

What I would like to do, is move the code that I have in the method, "downloadMovieData", into "fetchContentsOfURL", and return an `NSData` object which I can then use to populate the UITableView in my calling class.  However, in doing so, I would like to make sure I understand what is happening with the "completionHandler" portion of this new method.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't move it so it returns, because it's asynchronous. Technically you could, but you'd block the main thread while you wait which is bad.

Instead you simply replace the current code with a call to your singleton and in the completion block you call your other method to handle he data.

Couple of things to note:

1. It's a good idea to dispatch to main in your singleton before it call someone the completion block so you don't require all users of the function to remember to do it
2. It doesn't need to be a singleton, you can instantiating a copy of the class each time you need it or use dependency injection instead, both of which generally provide a better architecture

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply.  Could you please explain what you mean by "dependency injection" in this case (i.e. iOS)?

Comment: Dependency injection, in any language, is the process of supplying a class with its requirements by passing those values to it (injecting them) where that class would otherwise have code to go and get things to fill the requirements from somewhere else.